# Use a central dbase for different process flows and get access with a dynamic event

Tags: anylogic

So for now I have seperate the dbase of pallets which come into my process flows (source) and the pallets which should get picked to the time of my dbase with the number n. N is the number of pallets which get stored and picked.

```
dbase truck= pick pallets to the specified time when id (pallet.typeID) = id

dbase tor77_kunde1 = Process flow1: pallets come into source block with the data of this dbase

dbase tor77_kunde3 = Process flow2: pallets come into source block with the data of this dbase
```

So now I would like to use my truck dbase to pick the pallets from my different process flows when the id in my dbase truck = the id of my pallets which come into the source block (id of dbase tor77_kunde1 or tor77_kunde3). **How can I change my create_myDE function in Main and my dynamic event?** The process flows should only pick the pallets which came also into their source bock (because of that id should be typeid of pallets came into source).

MAIN:

```
List< Tuple > amounts =selectFrom( truck ).list();
for( Tuple tup : amounts ) {
    Date today=date();
    Date future=tup.get(truck.picktime);
    long diff = future.getTime() - today.getTime();
    int n =tup.get(truck.n);
    process.create_MyDynamicEvent(diff, MILLISECOND, n);
    process1.create_MyDynamicEvent(diff, MILLISECOND, n);
}
```

[image: flowchartDE]

[image: dbase_truck]

[image: dbasetor771]

[image: dbasetor773]

[image: process1and2]

Comment: Could you add more clarity around what is the current behavior in your code versus the expected behavior?